# Background when I want to add "box-shadow";

Tags: html, css

I have png picture without background. But when I tried to add box-shadow, this picture has it. How can I avoid it?
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////

HTML

```
<section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="section__image">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QAH8KJl.png" alt="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="section__info">
          <h3 class="section__name">
            Create an account
          </h3>
          <div class="section__text">
            Create/login to an existing
            account to get started
          </div>
          <div class="section__subtext">
            An account is created with your email
            and a desired password
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.section .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1272px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section__image img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 50px 30px 150px rgba(46, 4, 4, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 50px 30px 150px rgba(46, 4, 4, 0.15);
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.section__info {
  max-width: 56.8rem;
}
.section__name {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  color: #fa4a0c;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}
.section__text {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 57px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  color: #252b42;
  margin-bottom: 1.7rem;
}
.section__subtext {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  color: #737373;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, "this picture has it"?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: @Johannes look here https://jsfiddle.net/sufkyr8o/

Comment: If you can see, there is a little bit of white background near the image but the image in png with transparent background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `box-shadow`, which places a shadow around the frame of the image, you should instead be using the `drop-shadow()` filter.

Like this:

```
.section__image img {
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(50px 30px 150px rgba(46, 4, 4, 0.15));
        filter: drop-shadow(50px 30px 150px rgba(46, 4, 4, 0.15));
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```